# multiples entries for windows (UEFI) in the Grub list, which one is the good?

Tags: grub2

I just tried to install Ubuntu on my Asus X550C, and this is the first time I've had to deal with EFI and stuff. Now, my computer does launch on grub, but I have like 10 names for Windows (EFI, Launcher, Recovery etc...) and I'd just like to know which one I need to use to run Windows.

Additonal info if you need it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6120471/

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you'll want to use either the `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi` or `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi` entries. Those are Windows specific (and actually most likely copies of the same file with different names).

Comment: Are you seeing 10 entries in UEFI menu or in grub menu? Boot-Repair added correct entries as grub2's os-prober has a bug and does not create correct entries.